# How to set text orientation to vertical in SharePoint promoted links tiles?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, css

I am using SharePoint promoted links web part to show tiles on a page. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Now what I wanna do is,Change the Orientation to vertical for HR Forms, HR Calendar and Auditorium Booking so that it can appear in two lines. So for HR Forms, HR would be in first line and Forms would be in second so it can align with conference room booking text. I tried adding text-orientation attribute and set it to null but did not work. Can anyone please help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the style - `display:table-caption`

Be careful on the class that you are applying the style, so as to not affect any other areas :)